# Android AVD Bluetooth Activation Problem

Tags: android, bluetooth, activation, android-virtual-device

By default Bluetooth is not enabled in Android. But when I go to Setting > Wireless & network and I click on Bluetooth Settings I get the following error:

> 04-04 11:42:22.492:
>   WARN/dalvikvm(747): threadid=1: thread
>   exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40014760)  FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main  android.view.InflateException:
>   Binary XML file line #29: Error
>   inflating class
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor
>        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:397)
>        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItemFromTag(GenericInflater.java:430)
>        at android.preference.GenericInflater.rInflate(GenericInflater.java:481)
>        at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:326)
>        at android.preference.GenericInflater.inflate(GenericInflater.java:263)
>        at android.preference.
>   PreferenceManager.inflateFromResource(PreferenceManager.java:269)
>        at android.preference.PreferenceFragment.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceFragment.java:271)
>        at com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothSettings.addPreferencesForActivity(BluetoothSettings.java:53)
>        at com.android.settings.bluetooth.DeviceListPreferenceFragment.onActivityCreated(DeviceListPreferenceFragment.java:93)
>        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:749)
>        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:921)
>        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:578)
>        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1221)
>        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:375)
>        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
>        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
>        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)  Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native
>   Method)
>        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
>        at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:383)
>        ... 22 more  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>        at com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothNamePreference.setSummaryToName(BluetoothNamePreference.java:101)
>        at com.android.settings.bluetooth.BluetoothNamePreference.(BluetoothNamePreference.java:66)
>        ... 25 more

What I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant setup bluetooth on ANdroid AVD. Please check this link for emulator limitations:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html

Comment: Is there a way to test my bluetooth application in Android, without using a real device?